# é HTML Entity code in title tags

Tags: html, html-escape-characters

I'm trying to use the HTML entity code for 'é' in the title tags of my site, and it doesn't seem to be working in any browser. If I type the French equivalent of "Party:" in the title:

```
<title>part&eacute;</title>
```

I get `part&eacute;` in the title bar across all browsers when it renders. When I use the 'é' character, it actually works. Does anyone know what is up with this?

Comment: @Wobble — **element** not attribute

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome and Firefox on Linux. Perhaps an OS localization issue.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Entity references work fine (at least as fine as characters entered directly) in `title` elements. The problem is most probably caused by something that *looks like* an entity reference to an author when he looks at his files—the data that browsers get does not include it. Some software is used to generate the HTML document from some file that contains `&eacute;` but the software does not simply pass it forward but e.g. converts `&` to `&amp;`.

This can be checked using View Source in a browser.

Comment: Hit the nail on the head, this was exactly what was going on. Thanks Jukka!

Answer (score 3):

I tried

```
<!DOCTYPE html>     
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>&eacute;</title>
<div>&eacute;</div>
```

and it works (FF13)